# Prevent that Mozilla Thunderbird tracks its users

Tags: thunderbird, privacy, packages, tracking

Mozilla Thunderbird has a default setting in the preferences:
[image]

the end of this URL contains version, OS and a build ID.
`&version=45.6.0&os=Linux&buildid=2017010999999`

I expect that the combination of these three is unique on Gentoo Linux systems, but also for many other systems. In theory it is possible to collect who runs thunderbird when, on what OS, version and probably more (IP, location, ...).

**How can package maintainers (or users) prepare the installation in a way that new users will have a disabled checkbox by default.**

Comment: So what have you tried?  You should be able to modify default profile so the start page is something other then the site in the screenshot easily enough.

Comment: @Ramhound the goal should be, that not every user on a system has to change the default setting manually.

Comment: There is already a use flag on Gentoo Linux: `startup-notification - Enable application startup event feedback mechanism`. This may be a start. I have not found information about other distributions.